# How can I use InetAddressPoint in Lucene 6.5?

Tags: java, lucene

Can please somebody explain to me why the following doesn't work?

```
Document docObj = new Document();
InetAddress addr = null;
try {addr = InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1");}
catch (UnknownHostException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
if (addr != null)
    docObj.add(new InetAddressPoint("ipAddress", addr));
```

I'm importing `org.apache.lucene.document.InetAddressPoint` and I added the **.../lucene-6.5.0/sandbox/lucene-sandbox-6.5.0.jar** to my project, but my IDE (intellij) keeps on telling me that `InetAddressPoint` is unknown.

Comment: 1) check that the import is correct, 2) use `jar -t ...` to check that the JAR file contains that class, and 3) check that the JAR file has been added correctly; i.e. that it is actually on the buildpath.

Comment: I've checked that the class hasn't been moved.  I can see it in the 6.0.0 javadocs, and in the source code on github (latest version).  The package and class names are the same.  It hasn't moved.

Comment: I finally found it in `...\lucene-6.5.0\misc\lucene-misc-6.5.0.jar`. 
I used this windows command to search all jar files in the current folder and all its subfolders:
`for /R %G in (*.jar) do @jar -tvf "%G" | find "InetAddressPoint" > NUL && echo %G`